# Does put a match mean to fire a matchstick?

Tags: comprehension

**He put a match to a dry twig and with it lit the earthen lamp.**

It's a sentence from a translated text, origin of which is Urdu. Does the phrase put a match to a dry twig mean to fire a dry twig first with a matchstick and light the earthen lamp?

Comment: To _light_ a dry twig with a _match_.

Comment: The verb to "fire" something doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: And note that "put a match" to something doesn't require an actual match. Someone could actually use a cigarette lighter for example. The important part is using something small to start a larger, or at least longer lasting, fire.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your interpretation is correct.

He struck a match to create a flame, put the flaming match next to a dry twig so it caught on fire, and used the twig to light the earthen lamp.